# Every time i compile my project everything outside the while loop doesn't show up (input comes from file)

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\students.dat"));//Opened file

        int math=0,spanish=0,french=0,english=0,count=0,sum,highSpan=0,highMath=0,highFren=0,highEng=0;//Declarations
        double avg,highAvg=0;
        String name,highName;
        highName="";
        name = "";                      //Prime read
            while (name!="ENDDATA"){        //Sentinel condition
                count++;                    //Keeps count of students
                name = in.next();
                spanish=in.nextInt();
                math=in.nextInt();
                french=in.nextInt();
                english=in.nextInt();
                sum = spanish + math + french + english;
                avg = sum/4;                                    //Claculates Average
                System.out.printf("%s - %.0f\n",name,avg);

                    if (avg > highAvg){                         //Checks for the highest Average
                        highAvg = avg;
                        highName = name;
                    }
                    if (spanish > highSpan){
                        highSpan = spanish;
                    }
                    if (math > highMath){
                        highMath = math;                        //Checks for the highest mark for each subject
                    }
                    if (french > highFren){
                        highFren = french;
                    }
                    if (english > highEng){
                        highEng = english;
                    }

                name = in.nextLine();
            }

        System.out.printf("Number of students in class is: %d\n",count);
        System.out.printf("The highest student average is: %f\n",highAvg);
        System.out.printf("The student who made the highest average is: %s\n",highName);
        System.out.printf("The highest Spanish mark is: %d\n",highSpan);
        System.out.printf("The highest Math mark is: %d\n",highMath);
        System.out.printf("The highest French mark is: %d\n",highFren);
        System.out.printf("The highest English mark is: %d\n",highEng);
        in.close();                                                                 //Closing of file
    }
}
```

Write a Java program to read and process each line of the textfile and print the following
information (for each line except the last):
The number of students in the class
The name and average score for each student
The highest student average in the class (ignore the possibility of a tie)
The name of the student who attained the highest average (ignore the possibility of a tie)
The highest mark for each subject

its supposed to read the data form a dat file and make the necessary output but the print statements outside the while loop are not showing up also i get this output with the error below.

```
MARY - 65
SHELLY - 70
JOHN - 60
ALFRED - 71
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Statistics.main(Statistics.java:17)
```

Comment: It must be because your `while` loop is not done yet. Check your data. Since MARY, SHELLY, etc. successfully prints, then there must be something wrong with the data for a particular student.

Comment: Your errors show that `nextInt` is throwing an error and terminating the program. You should check your file and make sure the item you're trying to read really is an int. It would be best if you update your question with the content of the smallest **students.dat** which makes this error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in.nextInt() is throwing NoSuchElementException.

Your File seems to have improper data.

Your while loop will never break because your condition:

```
   while(name!="ENDDATA")
```

will always be true. That's why when all the token are exhausted the scanner object throws NoSuchElementException. And because of the exception your print statement after the while loops are not executed.

Try to use **hasNext()** method of scanner to check for the next token.

Replace your while loop with this while.

```
  while (in.hasNext()){        //Sentinel condition
            count++;                    //Keeps count of students
            name = in.next();
            if(name.equals("ENDDATA")){
               break;
            }
            spanish=in.nextInt();
            math=in.nextInt();
            french=in.nextInt();
            english=in.nextInt();
            sum = spanish + math + french + english;
            avg = sum/4;                                    //Claculates Average
            System.out.printf("%s - %.0f\n",name,avg);

                if (avg > highAvg){                         //Checks for the highest Average
                    highAvg = avg;
                    highName = name;
                }
                if (spanish > highSpan){
                    highSpan = spanish;
                }
                if (math > highMath){
                    highMath = math;                        //Checks for the highest mark for each subject
                }
                if (french > highFren){
                    highFren = french;
                }
                if (english > highEng){
                    highEng = english;
                }


 }
```

**Students.dat** file format should look like this:

```
Shelly 2 2 3 4
Brown 34 2 1 4
Pink 23 45 21 1
ENDDATA
```

Comment: question? if at the bottom of the file i have ENDDATA and i want to use it as a sentinel value to terminate the loop how would i do so

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of name = in.next() and name = in.nextLine() in the while loop.I think one is enough. 
For example:

name = in.next();
do{
.....
.... 
name = in.next();
}while(name!="ENDDATA");

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at the line `french=in.nextInt()`. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) says, `nextInt()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` when there is no more input to read.

> public int nextInt()
>
> Throws:
>
> NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted

Probably one of your entries in `student.dat` is not filled the way you expect it to be.